# zookeeper dependency for a maven project

Tags: java, maven, apache-zookeeper

Folks, 
I have JAVA Console app which depends on ZK. In the POM file for the project, the dependency I have given, for the ZK client libraries, is:

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
        <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.6</version>
  </dependency>
```

when I do

> mvn compile

I get

[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.4.6 is missing, no dependency information available

I am trying to download the ZK client libs on the fly. Not sure what am I doing wrong. Help would be appreciated.
thanks

Comment: Are you using nexus or other internal repository? If yes, make sure they have that version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
mvn dependency:resolve
```

before you compile

You can also try to download the single zk

```
mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:3.4.6
```

and see where it takes you.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.
running "get -Dartifact=org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:3.4.6" gave me an option to install the JAR file in the local maven repo so I did. and that worked. appreciate it.

Comment: Glad to hear, would you accept answer if you find it useful. Thanks!

Comment: Stanley, I clicked on the "green check box". I guess that's what you mean by accepting an answer.